# What is the SQL command to lock a table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

What is the `SQL` command to `lock` a `table` ? And how also to release the `lock` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to postgresql.org A lock is released at the end of the transaction. There is no way to manually 'unlock' a lock.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html

Comment: Isn'it mysql you are giving me ? I m lookig for a PostgreSQL command !

Comment: so you should change your answer :)

Comment: Any Time! I'm trying to get a better 'rep' but Im actually losing points 0.o

Comment: as I saw you should take care of what you are posting ! for example you answered me a mysql response although it is postgresql the question :)

Comment: Yeh I didn't think to read the tags! I'll get better. My problem is some old questions from almost a year ago! lol